# Javascript only playing first song with soundmanager2

Tags: javascript, jquery, soundmanager2

I'm using soundmanager2 to play some songs that have been uploaded. However, only the first song plays. The play button simply won't work for any other songs besides the first.

Javascript/html:

```
<% @tracks.each do |track| %>
  <tr>
    <td id="tracktitle"><%= track.title %></td>
    <td id="trackartist"><%= track.artist %></td>
    <td id="trackplayer"><%= image_tag 'play-button.gif', :id=>'play-button' %>
<%= image_tag 'stop-button.gif', :id=>'stop-button' %>


<script>
soundManager.setup({
  url: '/swf/',
  flashVersion: 9, // optional: shiny features (default = 8)
  // optional: ignore Flash where possible, use 100% HTML5 mode
  // preferFlash: false,
  onready: function() {
    soundManager.createSound({
      id: 'mySound',
      url: '<%= track.track_file %>',
      autoLoad: true,
      autoPlay: false,
      onload: function() {
        //alert('The sound '+this.id+' loaded!');
      },
      volume: 50
    });
  }
});
</script>
```

Tracks.js:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#play-button').click(function() {
        soundManager.play('mySound');
        $(this).toggle();
        $('#stop-button').toggle();
    });

    $('#stop-button').click(function() {
        soundManager.stop('mySound');
        $(this).toggle();
        $('#play-button').toggle();
    });
});
```

Probably a very newb problem, but can anybody spot where I'm going wrong? Many thanks in advance.

Comment: What does `.toggle()` do to the jQuery object?

Comment: The play button turns into the stop button

Answer (score 0):

It seems as if you have several play buttons with the same `#play-button` id, right?

I might be wrong, but as far as I know jQuery selectors will only look for the first matching element if the selector is an id. That means for track 2, 3...n the selector won't work at all.

You should be able to use a class like `.play-button` to trigger the toggle() action since jQuery selectors on classes are triggered for every matching element. However you might also need a way to distinguish between the individual tracks - if they are all called `mySound` how can SoundManager know which track to play? This is a problem I'm also dealing with, which initially led me to this question.